# Work-around for multiple access cases with strong_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, strong-parameters

I have an app where the User is allowed to access their :name, :lastname, :email attributes only once - during the initial account setup.  After this (for security reasons) they are not allowed to change either of these attributes; only an Admin can.

```
def user_params
    if current_user && current_user.admin?
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,
                                :surname,
                                :admin)
    else
      params.require(:user).permit()
    end
end
```

Then during `user.create` I allow the User to complete the registration form and access these protected attributes, but during `user.update`, only an Admin can change that information.

Since `user_params` is being called for each method (new, create, edit, update, show, destroy), it won't allow the user to write these attributes and set up an account if I restrict access to these attributes to Admins only after account creation/verification.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?  Or am I just missing something about strong_parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_params` is just a helper method so you don't have to repeat the same code in all of the actions. If the code in `create` is different from the code in `update`, just create another helper method:

```
def user_create_params
  if current_user && current_user.admin?
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :admin)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname)
  end
end

def user_update_params
  if current_user && current_user.admin?
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :admin)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit()
  end
end
```